# BASH - Delete files older than 3 months?

Tags: linux, bash, centos, find, delete-file

Delete files older than 3 months how?

For 90 days i know:

```
find /tmp/*.log -mtime +90 -type f -delete
```

But how do i know 3 months equal to always 90 days? how many exact days? Is there more better way to tell the `-mtime` to follow `months`?

Comment: Why is it so critical for you to use the inexact time-unit *month*?

Comment: Make it 93 days and just accept that you may have a delayed deletion of files for short periods. Life is too short for being picky :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want exact number of days for 3 months then you can use:

```
days=$(( ( $(date '+%s') - $(date -d '3 months ago' '+%s') ) / 86400 ))
```

and use it as:

```
find /tmp/*.log -mtime +$days -type f -delete
```

Or directly in `find`:

```
find /tmp/*.log -type f \
-mtime "+$(( ( $(date '+%s') - $(date -d '3 months ago' '+%s') ) / 86400 ))" -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, `find` supports other time difference options, including: `-amin`, `-atime`, `-cmin`, `-ctime`, `-mmin`, and `-mtime`.

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# For example, today is 2023-12-12.
# Let's find all files since the start of the month (i.e. 2023-12-01).

declare currentSecs="$( date -u -- '+%s'; )";
declare previousSecs="$( date -ud '2023-12-01' -- '+%s'; )";

find . -mmin "-$(( (currentSecs - previousSecs) / 60 ))";
```

---

```bash
# -mmin n
# File's data was last modified less than, more than or exactly n minutes ago.
```

Source: `man find` (`find (GNU findutils) 4.8.0`).